# articles in English

Tags: grammar, articles

Most of the time I understand how to use articles, but when it comes to certain sentences I start to lose confidence.

Could anyone please consider the following uses? In each case I am  trying to explain how I see it, any corrections or answers are welcome. (Maybe somebody has links to some pieces of texts, where each article is explained, if so then please post a link here)

**A.**

> (**1**)The potential disruptions in (**2**)the functioning of (**3**) an integrated global monetary system could result in (**4**)a renewed global economic meltdown as well as (**5**)a drop off in (**6**)international commodity trade.

1. Perhaps disruptions were mentioned earlier? But if they were not, does it mean that they are specific? (we know that they stem from "...the functioning of..." and that they "could result in...")
2. As I understand, we can use *the* before a noun if it is followed by "of something"?
3. Isn't "integrated global monetary system" something unique? (thus requring using *the*).

**B.**

> This global oversupply of commodities is (**1**)a  direct consequence of the decline in purchasing power and rising levels of poverty [.] (**2**)Oversupply contributes in turn to the further depression of the earnings of the direct producers through the closure of excess productive capacity.

1. Isn't "direct consequence" something specific? It is indicated what is the essence of this consequence (that is, "global oversupply") and we can see that the consequence occurred due to "the decline in" . This question correlates with **A**.(**2**).
2. The absence of the definite article in (**2**) is not clear. Maybe it is a mistake. Maybe it is an uncountable, general noun. However, could (or should) we use *the* as we have a connection with the previously mentioned "global oversupply". The second sentence sounds for me like "[this] oversupply contributes..."

**C.**

> The legal basis for CEEPUS is (**1**)an international Agreement signed by the member states and open for accession.

1. Isn't a particular "international agreement(that was signed...and then serving as "the legal basis" for a particular thing )" implied here (thus, requiring *the*)?

**D**.

> [It] is a two-year Program that provides the(**1**) students with the(**2**) essential insights, capabilities and intellectual tools to analyse the legal problems of the information society

1. Why is *the* used? I can assume that, for example, enrolled (thus, particular) students are implied there. However can we use zero article if we are talking, for example, about any and all students (that is, indefinite 'population' of students) who are interested in this program.
2. Why is *the* used? I can assume that these insights were mentioned somewhere earlier (in other sections describing this particular program). Or *the* is used because they are  somewhat particular insights, that is "essential insights ... to analyse [smth]" however these 'insights' still sound to me like an abstract concept - infinite set of such essential insights. (And not a particular set of some cognitive processes) because there is not any strong description of them. Each student can obtain a different set of skills/methods and a different level of knowledge to analyse the problems. Thus there can be infinite set of such essential insights.

Comment: ^ NOT the duplicate of Are... ^_^ btw, thnx for editing.

Comment: **A** is what I would call a parallel hypothetical. **B** allows that there may be more than one consequence, and "oversupply" is spoken of in a general context, not a specific one. In **C**, CEEPUS is acknowledged to be one among a host of international agreements, and in **D** "students" may be referenced earlier (but the article is not necessary) and *the* is used before "essential insights" to link them necessarily to the verb of the sentence.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is SE-speak. It simply means that the referenced question probably contains the answer you're looking for. Note that it may be cast slightly differently. You're asking about particular cases; the referenced question explains the general rule. So while it may not be a "duplicate", this question essentially asks that one.

Comment: This is a duplicate in the sense that the referred question will help. It doesn't answer the specifics, it's true, but if you need answers to these particular questions, you are better off asking in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) (you'll need 20 rep). Otherwise, it is too localized to help future visitors. Also, generally speaking, it is best to ask *one* focused question (with possibly related questions) than to ask many, many questions in one post. It makes it much easier to answer.

Comment: thnx for your responses. definitely, I want all/some the sub-questions answered and indeed, they are anyway related to the previously asked ones... however, I believe that my main goal was to find some materials, where some pieces of texts are given and articles are explained. ...or a somewhat comprehensive guide to articles exists with more 'hard' cases/situations related to the usage of articles (not 'A man has a dog, the dog is blue')...